# Class that logs, android activities

Tags: android, class

I have an idea for an app, but I don't know exactly how to start programming it. Actually the hardest part is that:

Is there a class that gets notified when (for example) the message icon has been clicked or let's say the settings menu has been opened?

I would like to make an app that logs certain phone activities. Like: Settings has been opened at 10pm, phone was last unlocked at 9.59pm, etc.

Can you push me in right direction? Don't need to code, I will be glad just with class name or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a class that gets notified when (for example) the message icon has been clicked or let's say the settings menu has been opened?

No, sorry.

If you poke around StackOverflow and blogs, you will find various workarounds, typically involving polling. Some comments by Dianne Hackborn at the 2012 Google I|O conference suggest that Android will be more aggressively stopping such apps.

You are welcome to implement your own home screen, in which case you will find out when users tap on home screen icons because they are your icons.